# Matrix solution to solve c1, c2, c3

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

**Task:**
Determine which of the given numbers is the second coordinate of the vector x=`[4; 5; 0]` in the base {b1, b2, b3} where b1=`[2; 1; 3]`, b2=`[3; 1; 4]` and b3=`[-1; 3; 1]`

**Given numbers:**
2, -1, -3 or 1

**My answer:**
I guess that I should use c1*b1+c2*b2+c3*b3=x and in that way calculate each value of c1, c2 and c3.

c1*[2; 1; 3]+c2*[3; 1; 4]+c3*[-1; 3; 1]=[4; 5; 0]

2*c1+3*c2-c3=4

c1+c2+3*c3=5

3*c1+4*c2+c3=0

I get it to:

3c1-4*c2+c3=0

0+17c2+c3=12

0+0+43*c3=57

How do i do?

Comment: Do you mean the system $$2c_1+3c_2-c_3=4$$ $$c_1+c_2+3c_3=5$$,$$3c_1+4c_2+c_3=0$$?

Comment: yeah I mean that system

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Multiplying the second equation by $(-2)$ and adding to the first
$$c_2-7c_3=-6$$
multiplying the second equation by $-3$ and adding to the third then we get
$$c_2-8c_3=-15$$
and from here we obtain $$-c_3=-9$$
Can you finish now?

Comment: that gives me that c3=9, c2=57 and c1=-79. Am I correct? and the answer Is to determine if c2 (second coordinate) is equal to either 2, -1, -3 or 1...

Comment: I have $$c_1=-79,c_2=57,c_3=9$$

Comment: what should I then answer. What value does the second coordinate have of the vector x?

Comment: What coordinate do you mean?

Comment: the answer in the task that we are solving is what number does the second coordinate have of vector x. (Numbers to pick between; 2 or -1 or -3 or 1)

Comment: Do you mean the system $$2b_1+3b_2-b_3=4$$,$$b_1+b_2+3b_3=y$$,$$3b_1+4b_2+b_3=1$$?

Comment: Yeah I guess it is

Comment: How do i solve the coordinate